# wildfly 14 + pooled-connection-factory min-pool-size

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

In wildfly activemq subsystem, I have defined min-pool-size to 40 in pooled-connection-factory. Deploy artemis externally and define ip and port in wildfly standalone-full-ha.xml. After starting artemis and wildfly server, how can i verify that wildfly is created connection (based on min-pool-size property) once server started?

Comment: I'll explain in comment as I'm not sure it'll work (I'm basing this off working on JBoss 7.1.3, but should be similar). **1** Open `standalone.xml`, search for `management-http` port. **2** Browse to <WF-IP>:<port>, supply credentials of manager user. **3** You should be able to navigate to ActiveMQ and see the pool. I don't have ActiveMQ, but I can at least see the datasources and the current pool metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the pool in Wildfly is filled lazily so I don't believe that just starting Wildfly will necessarily cause a connection to be created. Something actually needs to use the pool to ensure it's working as expected. Confirming that the application using the pool is working as expected is the best way to know whether or not the pool is working as expected.

Also, I don't think the `pooled-connection-factory` actually exposes any metrics via the Wildfly management interfaces so that's probably why you're not seeing anything for it.